# Two different image behaviours within the same DIVs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently working on a website for a client, based on a theme called **'moderna'** [(link)](http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/index.html).

As you can see on the link, there is a grey text box that hovers over the slider, and I made it fill the whole width of the image, then I centered the text horizontally in the middle, and I want to add and center a pictogram over each text in this box, as seen here:

[image]

The problem that I'm having is that currently the icon doesn't align to the middle.
I think it's because of this line of code that makes the background images of the slider the width of the website (responsive):

```
.flexslider .slides img { width: 100%; display: block;}
```

When I turn this off, code lines that aim at centering / scaling the icons work perfectly. But of course, I can't delete or modify this part of the slider's code, as whenever I do it it stops being responsive or stops being 100% width.

Here's what I have:

```css
#featured .flexslider {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 0 30px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
}
.flex-caption {
  background: none;
  -ms-filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000, endColorstr=#4C000000);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000, endColorstr=#4C000000);
  zoom: 1;
}
.flex-caption {
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(12, 85, 154, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-caption h3 {
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.flex-caption p {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- start slider -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!-- Slider -->
      <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider text-center">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/img/slides/1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="flex-caption">
              <h3><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb" style="width:70px;height:70px;" />
                <br>Residential Services</h3> 
              <p>Duis fermentum auctor ligula ac malesuada. Mauris et metus odio, in pulvinar urna</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn-medium btn-theme">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/img/slides/2.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="flex-caption">
              <h3><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/careers/careers-icon.png?v=0288ba302bf6" style="width:70px;height:70px;" />
                <br>Commercial Services</h3> 
              <p>Sodales neque vitae justo sollicitudin aliquet sit amet diam curabitur sed fermentum.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn-medium btn-theme">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/img/slides/3.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="flex-caption">
              <h3><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb"  style="width:70px;height:70px;" />
                <br>GoGreen Services</h3> 
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit donec mer lacinia.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn-medium btn-theme">Learn More</a
    </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- end slider -->
```

The .png images are the icons that I want to center.
But if I change the CSS for the images in this div, the slider image changes as well.
I've been able to get the icon to be in the center with the slider not full-width, or have the slider's background image work fine, but the icons are full width (so, very huge) or just aligned to the very left of the text frame.

I haven't been able to add a div to the icons without breaking the appearance.

I am wondering how to code this so that these two images in the same div can behave / display differently, and yet not cancel out each other's features / appearance. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Andrew Sadly, I do not understand how to paste which files into JSFiddle to make a fiddle (there are 10 CSS sheets of more than 7000 lines for some of them... ) That said, I welcome a tutorial on JSFiddle, to understand how I could extract just the code bits needed for the slider in this precise situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should do the trick:

```
.flexslider .slides .flex-caption img {
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

Then images inserted into the caption box (grey box) should be original size (not 100%).

EDIT

Also add `display: inline;`

Comment: You mean, instead of ".flexslider .slides img { width: 100%; display: block;}", right?
This indeed makes the icon centered in the middle and the right size, but the slider's background images shrinks (two white margins on left and right), and becomes unresponsive (stays the same size when I resize window).

Comment: Not instead, add my code after `.flexslider .slides img`

Comment: Thank you! This solved my question! Awesome and so simple!

Answer (score 0):

> I checked the library [FlexSlider.css](https://cdn.rawgit.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/flexslider.css) and clean a bit some useless
>   lines, and add a snippet with related links to have a cool demo.

Your `.flex-caption` have a `position: absolute` related to the viewport, and not related like we want with the `.slides li`.
Set `position: relative` to the slide.

```
.flexslider .slides li {
  position: relative;
}
```

## To center your flex-caption's image, you have two solutions:

- `display: inline` && `text-align:center`

> By setting the bootstrap class `text-center` into the div
>   `.flexslider`, you applied the propriety `text-align: center` that
>   involve childs elements with propriety `display: inline` be centered.

So, in your case you just have to add into `.flexslider .slides .flex-caption img` the propriety `display: inline`.

```
.flexslider .slides .flex-caption img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline;
}
```

---

- `display: block` && `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`

you can also centering the image by setting it like a `display: block` and apply to him: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

```
.flexslider .slides .flex-caption img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

> Please avoid css inline in your html and set it on the css (cf. height and width in css)

## Demo:

```css
    .flexslider {
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .flexslider .slides .flex-caption {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background: rgba(12, 85, 154, 0.5);
      -ms-filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000, endColorstr=#4C000000);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000, endColorstr=#4C000000);
      zoom: 1;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 25px 25px 25px 30px;
    }
    .flexslider .slides .flex-caption h3 {
      color: #fff;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
    .flexslider .slides .flex-caption p {
      margin: 0 0 15px;
    }
    .flexslider .slides li {
      position: relative;
    }
    .flexslider .slides .flex-caption img {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/flexslider.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- start slider -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!-- Slider -->
          <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider text-center">
            <ul class="slides">
              <li>
                <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/img/slides/1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h3><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb" alt="Residential Services Icon" />
                    <br>Residential Services</h3> 
                  <p>Duis fermentum auctor ligula ac malesuada. Mauris et metus odio, in pulvinar urna</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn-medium btn-theme">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/img/slides/2.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h3><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/careers/careers-icon.png?v=0288ba302bf6" alt="Commercial Services Icon" />
                    <br>Commercial Services</h3> 
                  <p>Sodales neque vitae justo sollicitudin aliquet sit amet diam curabitur sed fermentum.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn-medium btn-theme">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/img/slides/3.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="flex-caption">
                  <h3><img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb" alt="GoGreen Services Icon" />
                    <br>GoGreen Services</h3> 
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit donec mer lacinia.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn-medium btn-theme">Learn More</a
        </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <!-- end slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide"
          });
        });
      })(jQuery); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```